# Apply the Girsanov theorem, determine the stochastic dynamics of $S^{(1)}$ and determine the risk-neutral price of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm not sure if I'm applying Change of Numeraire and Girsanov correctly in part c) and d). Also with the information I got, I don't know how to get a result for e).

Consider a financial market with 2 stocks and a bank account $S_t^{(0)}=1$ for $0\le t\le T$, i.e. the riskless interest rate is $r=0$. Under a risk-neutral martingale measure $Q$, assume the following dynamics of 2 stock prices $\{S_t^{(1)}\}_{0 \le t \le T}$ and $\{S_t^{(2)}\}_{0 \le t \le T}$:

$$dS_t^{(1)}=\sigma_{11}S_t^{(1)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}$$ with  $S_0^{(1)}>0$, and

$$dS_t^{(2)}=\sigma_{21}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma_{22}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)}$$ with $S_0^{(2)}>0$,
with constants $\sigma_{11}$,$\sigma_{21}$,$\sigma_{22}$. Note that $\{\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}\}_{0 \le t \le T}$ and $\{\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)}\}_{0 \le t \le T}$ are 2 independent standard Brownian motions under the risk-neutral martingale measure $Q$. It is further assumed that the matrix  \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_{11}&0\\\sigma_{21}&\sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix} is irreversible.

**a)** Using Itô's formula, show that the solution of the SDE,

$dS_t^{(2)}=\sigma_{21}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma_{22}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)}$, with $S_0^{(2)}>0$
is given by

$S_t^{(2)}=S_0^{(2)} \exp(\frac{-1}{2}(\sigma_{21}^2+\sigma_{22}^2)t+\sigma_{21}\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma_{22}\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)} )$.

**My solution for a)**
One can see this by applying, $df=f_tdt+f_xdW_t+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}d\langle W\rangle_t$
On get then $dS_t^{(2)}=-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma^2_{21}+ \sigma^2_{22})S_t^{(2)}dt+\sigma^2_{21}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma^2_{22}S_t^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)}+\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_{21}^2dt+\sigma_{22}^2dt)$
where here is important to see that since the $\widetilde{W}_t^{(i)}$ are independent, $d\widetilde{W}_t^{(1)}d\widetilde{W}_t^{(2)}=0$.
If we simplify we get the desired solution.

**b)** Explain why we can use the risk-neutral valuation formula to price any contingent claim $X$ in this financial market.

**My solution for b)** Since the market is complete, due to the fact that the matrix with sigma is invertible and that we are under a risk-neutral martingale measure, we can use risk-neutral valuation to price any contingent claim $X$

**c)** Consider the following contingent claim or derivative

$$X(T)=S_T^{(2)}1_{\{S_T^{(1)}>K\}}$$.

Using "Change of Numeraire" and $S^{(2)}$ as numeraire, show that the risk-neutral price $\Pi_0^X$ of the contingent claim $X$ at time $t=0$ is given by

$$\Pi_0^X=S_0^{(2)} E_{Q^1}[1_{\{S_T^{(1)}>K\}}]$$
wherethe measure $Q^1$ has to be determined, i.e. determine its Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to $Q$
$$\frac{dQ^1}{dQ}|F_t$$

**my solution to c)**

One has $$\frac{dQ^1}{dQ}|F_t=\frac{N_t}{S_t^{(0)}}\frac{S_0^{(0)}}{N_0}$$
since new numeraire is supposed to be $S^{(2)}$ and $S_t^{(0)}=1$ for all $t$ ($r=0$) we get
$$\frac{dQ^1}{dQ}|F_t=\frac{S_t^{(2)}}{1}\frac{1}{S_0^{(2)}}$$
and one has
$\Pi_0^X=1*E_Q[S_T^{(2)}1_{\{S_T^{(1)}>K\}}]=S_0^{(2)}E_{Q^1}[1_{\{S_T^{(1)}>K\}}]$

**d)** Consider the probability measure $Q^1$ from (c). Applying Girsanov theorem, determine **the stochastic dynamics** of $S^{(1)}$ under $Q^1$.
Knowing that a general SDE of this form
$$dSt=\hat{\mu} S_tdt+\hat{\sigma}S_td\hat{W}_t$$ with, $S_0>0$
has the solution
$$St=S_0\exp((\hat{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma})t+\hat{\sigma}\hat{W}_t)$$
write down the **solution of the derived SDE**.

**my solution to d)** **(Updated)** Using Girsanov we know that for any equivalent measure we have

$$\frac{dQ^1}{dQ}=\frac{S_T^{(2)}}{1}\frac{1}{S_0^{(2)}}=L_T$$
but at the same time
$$L_T=\exp\{-\int_0^T \gamma_s^{(1)}d\widetilde{W}_s^{(1)}
-\int_0^T \gamma_s^{(2)}d\widetilde{W}_s^{(2)}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T(\gamma_s^{(1)})^2+(\gamma_s^{(2)})^2ds\}$$
since we know that $S_T^{(2)}/S_0^{(2)}=\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_{21}^2+\sigma_{22}^2)T+\sigma_{21}\widetilde{W}_T^{(1)}+\sigma_{22}\widetilde{W}_T^{(2)})$, it follows that $\gamma_t^{(1)}=-\sigma_{21}$ and $\gamma_t^{(1)}=-\sigma_{22}$.

Now using the fact that $d\hat{W}_t^{(i)}=d\widetilde{W}_t^{(i)}+\gamma_t^{(i)}dt$ are Brownian motions under $Q^1$

Applying this to $dS_t^{(1)}=\sigma_{11}S_t^{(1)}(d\hat{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma_{21}dt)$
gives $\hat{\mu}=\sigma_{21}\sigma_{11}$ and $\hat{\sigma}=\sigma_{11}$

**e)** Combining results from c) and d), determine the risk-neutral price of this derivative $X(T)$ at time $t=0$

**Solution to e (according to suggestion)**
Ok. Since my calculation is correct, I just need to calculate the following now: (I'm taking $S_0^{(2)}$ out of the calculations since it's a constant)

$E_{Q^1}[1_{\{S_T^{(1)}>K\}}]=Q^1(S_T^{1}>K)=Q^1(S_0^{(1)}\exp((\sigma_{11}\sigma_{21}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}^2)T+\sigma_{11}\hat{W}_T^{(1)})$

and after moving some terms, using the fact that $-W_t=W_t$ and that $W_t\sim N(0,t)$,

$=Q^1(\frac{\ln(\frac{S_0^{(1)}}{K})+(\sigma_{11}\sigma_{12}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}^2)T}{\sigma_{11}\sqrt T}> Z)$

where Z is standard normal distribution.

Comment: You found out correctly that under $Q^1\,,$ $dS_t^{(1)}=\sigma_{11}\,(d\hat{W}_t^{(1)}+\sigma_{21}\,dt)\,.$ This tells you how $S_t^{(1)}$ looks like. Then $E_{Q'}[1_{\{S_t^{(1)}>K\}}]$ follows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm frankly not sure how to calculate the expectation there... should I just write it down as a probability (since its an indicator function inside the expectation?)

Comment: This expectation is nothing else than $Q'(S_t^{(1)}>K)\,.$ Let me know if that hint helps.

Comment: Im writting down what I think is the solution in the question now.

Comment: Looks right. A more standard way of writing this is to use the standard normal cdf $\Phi\,:$ $Q'(S_T^{(1)}>K)=\Phi(d)$ where $$d=\frac{\ln(\frac{S_0^{(1)}}{K})+(\sigma_{11}\sigma_{12}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}^2)T}{\sigma_{11}\sqrt T}\,.$$ (I hope I got all the signs right.)